# Disabling a shortcut while typing

Tags: keyboard, automation, shortcut, autohotkey

I used following AutoHotKey code to display the "Go to page" dialog in Adobe Reader:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#ifWinActive Adobe Reader
    p:: Send ^+n
#ifWinActive
```

The problem is that it prevents me from typing the <kbd>P</kbd> key in find text box. How can I disable that shortcut while typing?

Comment: Reza, Do you launch search through ^f and end with {Enter}? In that case we could use this to trigger the beginning and end.

Comment: Yes, I use ^f and end with {Enter}.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to press p in Acrobat Reader and jump to the next page. When you press ^f to search, pressing <kbd>p</kbd> will just result is a p being sent, until you press Enter, which will return the pressing <kbd>p</kbd> behavior into sending ^N again.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Put this line in the beginning of your script to allow flexible searching in the window title.

#ifWinActive Adobe Reader ; The following lines ONLY work inside Acrobat Reader.
    ~^f::ARSearchActive = 1 ; Let ^f go through to the O/S and set a variable.
    ~Enter::ARSearchActive = 0 ; Let Enter go through to the O/S and reset the variable.

    p:: ; Action to do when p is pressed
    If (ARSearchActive = 1) ; This is true AFTER you pressed ^f.
        Send, p ; If search has been activated, just send p
    else ; This is true after you pressed Enter.
        Send, ^+n ; If search is not activated, send ^N
    Return
#ifWinActive ; End of Adobe Reader specific portion.
```

I have NOT tested this with Acrobat Reader, as I use Foxit, but I tested it with Notepad, where it performed as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I type in Adobe Reader, at least for finding

Comment: see my answer for a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on your comment that you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the search box, type the text, and end by pressing enter:

**Edited** the code based on the OPs comment:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

mode := "hotkey_mode"

#If, WinActive("Adobe Reader") && mode = "hotkey_mode"
    p:: Send ^+n

    ~^f::
        Hotkey If, WinActive("Adobe Reader") && mode = "hotkey_mode"
        Hotkey p, off
    return

    ~Enter::
    ~Esc::
        Hotkey IfWinActive, Adobe Reader
        Hotkey p, on
    return

    ^t::mode := "typing_mode"   

#If, WinActive("Adobe Reader") && mode = "typing_mode"
    ^t::mode := "hotkey_mode" 
#If
```

I have added an <kbd>ESC</kbd> hotkey to do the same thing as <kbd>Enter</kbd>, because you might use <kbd>ESC</kbd> to quit the find dialog. Additionally, in my version of Adobe Reader pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is also used as a shortcut for *Find Next*, so if I were you I would disable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> hotkey and use only <kbd>ESC</kbd> to escape the find dialog.

Finally, a general tip: It is usually easier to use hotkeys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> than just <kbd>p</kbd> to avoid complications like these. In fact if you don't use the print command which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> triggers, you might consider using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> instead of <kbd>p</kbd> as your hotkey (or even if you do print, but only rarely, since you would still be able to still access the print command from the menu)

Comment: Thanks, it there a way that I disable all single-key shortcuts while typing in a concise manner ?

Comment: @Hirmanshu, Nice addition and different approach to the problem!

Comment: @Reza, in that situation I would probably try the route of using suspend and run one general script (if you have more hotkeys outside Acrobat) which is always running and one script for Acrobat which you can toggle on/off through suspend.

Comment: @Reza, like I said in my post, single key hotkeys are not a good idea in general. I mean why would you want to have single key hotkeys when you use those keys to type text?
But if you did insist on having them, you could have two modes, a 'typing mode' and a 'hotkey mode'. You can define a hotkey to switch between these modes. (You would need AutoHotkey_L, if you're not already using it, to create a `#If mode = <mode_name>` condition)

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya Thanks, can you please add modes to you code snippet? While single-key shortcut are defined by programmer they work so well, indeed Adobe Reader have some single-key shortcut if you active it in its preferences window. I thing AuotoHoKey should propose a solution to constrain some shortcut to non-typing mode.

Comment: I get what you're saying about the "typing mode". But there is no way AHK can tell when an application is in "typing mode" or not (because applications often use non-standard/custom text boxes). While the application itself obviously knows it in typing mode.
Anyway, check out the edited code. I have quickly made some changes without testing anything. You might need to tweak things around to get it to work like you want. **You will need AHK_L to run this**

Comment: @HimanshuPokhariya, Thank you for pointing out the #IF. Even though I use AHK_L, I had not seen the #IF...

Comment: How can I modify first part of condition to `#IfWinActive ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow`?